# Index beyond bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexing, nsarray, indexoutofboundsexception

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but none of the answers helped me with my issue.

I have function when I move one window around:

```
-(void)flowLayout:(SEssentialsFlowLayout *)flow didDragView:(UIView *)view{
    NSLog(@"drag");
    BOOL needDeleteFavourites = NO;

    CGPoint dragScrollPosition =  [flow convertPoint:view.center toView:self];
    CGPoint dragPosition =  [flow convertPoint:view.center toView:self.scroll];

    // original grupe view

    UIGroupView * orgGrView = (UIGroupView *)flow.superview.superview;
    UIScrollView * orgScroll = (UIScrollView *)flow.superview;



    for (SEssentialsFlowLayout * destinationFlow in self.flows) {
        // destination grupe view
        UIGroupView * grView = (UIGroupView *)destinationFlow.superview.superview;
        UIScrollView * scroll = (UIScrollView *)destinationFlow.superview;

        if (flow != destinationFlow && grView.grupes.type == GrupeTypeEditable) {
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(destinationFlow.superview.superview.frame, dragPosition)) {

                view.center = [scroll convertPoint:dragPosition toView:scroll];

                // calculate cube space

                int numberOfCubeOnScreen = grView.frame.size.width / (grView.frame.size.height * grView.cubeWidth) ;
                int delta = grView.frame.size.width - (grView.frame.size.height * grView.cubeWidth * numberOfCubeOnScreen);
                float oneDelta = (float) delta/(numberOfCubeOnScreen );

                // destination grupe view
                int numberOfpage = ceil((grView.frame.size.height * grView.cubeWidth + oneDelta)* (destinationFlow.managedViews.count + 2) / grView.frame.size.width);
                destinationFlow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, grView.frame.size.width * numberOfpage, grView.frame.size.height * 0.68);

                scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(destinationFlow.frame.size.width, destinationFlow.frame.size.height);
                [grView.pageControll setNumberOfPages:numberOfpage];



                if (orgGrView.grupes.type == GrupeTypeNotEditable) {
                    // grabcube view
                    UICubeVeiw * oldCubeView = (UICubeVeiw *)view;

                    // create new cube and new cube view
                    Cube * newCube = [oldCubeView.cube copyCube];
                    UICubeVeiw * newCubeVew = [oldCubeView copyCubeView:oldCubeView.cube];

                    // copy new cube into old cube view
                    oldCubeView.cube = newCube;

                    // add new cube view on old flow
                    int newIndex = [flow.managedViews indexOfObject:view];
                    if (newIndex > 0 && newIndex< flow.managedViews.count) {
                        [flow unmanageSubview:view];
                        [flow addManagedSubview:newCubeVew atIndex:newIndex];

                        // move old cube view on new flow
                        [destinationFlow addManagedSubview:view];
                    }
                }
                else{

                    // original grupe view
                    int orgNumberOfpage = ceil((orgGrView.frame.size.height * grView.cubeWidth +oneDelta ) * (flow.managedViews.count ) / orgGrView.frame.size.width);
                    flow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, orgGrView.frame.size.width * orgNumberOfpage, orgGrView.frame.size.height * 0.68);

                    orgScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(flow.frame.size.width, flow.frame.size.height);
                    [orgGrView.pageControll setNumberOfPages:orgNumberOfpage];

                    [flow unmanageSubview:view];
                    [destinationFlow addManagedSubview:view];

                    [orgGrView.grupes removeCube:((UICubeVeiw *)view).cube];

                }

                needDeleteFavourites = YES;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"pozicija originala          :     %f ", orgGrView.grupes.positionIndex);
    if (orgGrView.grupes.positionIndex == 1 && needDeleteFavourites && orgGrView.grupes.cubes.count<1) {
        NSLog(@"remove");
        [self removeFavouritesFromView];
    }

    // move scroll view up and down
    if (dragScrollPosition.y < self.frame.size.height * 0.16) {
        NSLog(@"move down");
        if (!self.timerIsSet) {
            NSLog(@"move down 1");
            self.timerIsSet = YES;
            NSLog(@"move down 2");
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(moveScrollVeiwUp) userInfo:nil repeats:NO ];

        }
    }
    else if (dragScrollPosition.y > self.frame.size.height * 0.88) {
        if (!self.timerIsSet) {
            NSLog(@"move up");
            self.timerIsSet = YES;
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self selector:@selector(moveScrollVeiwDown) userInfo:nil repeats:NO ];

        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"move none");
        self.timerIsSet = NO;
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;

        self.isFavouriteCurrentlyVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

I know it is a lot of code, but when I move this window around I get strange error:

```
pozicija originala          :     1.000000 
2013-09-23 20:20:31.772 BIView Mobile[659:60b] move down
2013-09-23 20:20:31.774 BIView Mobile[659:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483646 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2db25f53 0x382996af 0x2da5c5f3 0x94667 0x942a1 0x93f1f 0x92171 0x918bf 0x91759 0x3041d98d 0x302c83e3 0x30652eed 0x3028f28b 0x3028d9d3 0x302c6c41 0x302c65e7 0x3029ba25 0x3029a221 0x2daf118b 0x2daf065b 0x2daeee4f 0x2da59ce7 0x2da59acb 0x32734283 0x302fba41 0x71655 0x387a1ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

This mean, if I understand correctly, that I should get some invalid index somewhere and look into array with it.

But I always check if index is in the bounds of acceptable values.

EDIT :

As I was advised I put exception breakpoint, but unfortunately breakpoint stops on :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I printed out stack trace if helps :

```
2013-09-24 11:48:10.683 BIView Mobile[890:60b] Uncaught exception: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2147483646 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]
2013-09-24 11:48:10.755 BIView Mobile[890:60b] Stack trace: (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2db25f6b <redacted> + 154
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x382996af objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2da5c5f3 <redacted> + 230
3   BIView Mobile                       0x000e34ef -[FlowPicker isLeftMost:inOrdering:] + 58
4   BIView Mobile                       0x000e3129 -[FlowPicker widenedSubviewExcludingView:inOrdering:] + 640
5   BIView Mobile                       0x000e2da7 -[FlowPicker indexOfPoint:currentBounds:currentIndex:inOrdering:excludingView:] + 118
6   BIView Mobile                       0x000e0ff9 -[FlowEdit changeEdit:] + 524
7   BIView Mobile                       0x000e0747 -[FlowEdit fireChangeEdit:afterTimeout:] + 342
8   BIView Mobile                       0x000e05e1 -[FlowEdit handleLongPress:] + 360
9   UIKit                               0x3041d98d <redacted> + 196
10  UIKit                               0x302c83e3 <redacted> + 1138
11  UIKit                               0x30652eed <redacted> + 48
12  UIKit                               0x3028f28b <redacted> + 218
13  UIKit                               0x3028d9d3 <redacted> + 282
14  UIKit                               0x302c6c41 <redacted> + 772
15  UIKit                               0x302c65e7 <redacted> + 666
16  UIKit                               0x3029ba25 <redacted> + 196
17  UIKit                               0x3029a221 <redacted> + 7096
18  CoreFoundation                      0x2daf118b <redacted> + 14
19  CoreFoundation                      0x2daf065b <redacted> + 206
20  CoreFoundation                      0x2daeee4f <redacted> + 622
21  CoreFoundation                      0x2da59ce7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
22  CoreFoundation                      0x2da59acb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
23  GraphicsServices                    0x32734283 GSEventRunModal + 138
24  UIKit                               0x302fba41 UIApplicationMain + 1136
25  BIView Mobile                       0x000bf55b main + 226
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x387a1ab7 <redacted> + 2
)
```

Comment: So what does the debugger say?

Comment: If would be helpful if you could identify the precise line which is generating this error. If the app is crashing without showing you where this is happening, try adding an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) for all exceptions.

Comment: hi, I try that but exception breakpoint stop at @autoreleasepool return UIAplicationMain....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That returned index `2147483646` happens to be `NSNotFound` on certain architectures. One of your statements (maybe `[flow.managedViews indexOfObject:view]`) appears to be returning `NSNotFound`, you should check for it.

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but I insert if (newIndex > 0 && newIndex< flow.managedViews.count) {} so I would avoid this bug

Comment: apparently this didn't solve my problem. And as you said, this error mean NSNotFound not really out of bounds

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. This should be easy to diagnose. The crash log clearly shows that you used an index of `NSNotFound` to access an array. `NSNotFound` will always also be out of bounds.

Comment: Do you have some suggestion where to start or how to debug this. I try everything I know, and I just can't find it

Comment: If you run a debug build on the simulator, that crash should automatically open the debugger for you. The stack trace on the left would show exactly where it happens. If not, go to the breakpoint tab, click the '+' in the bottom left, and select "Add Exception breakpoint". That should cause your app to break on every exception.   If it breaks on C++ exceptions (which might be on purpose in some libraries), right-click the Exceptions breakpoint you added above, select 'Edit breakpoint" and change "Exception" from "All" to "Objective-C". Good luck!